# Ant jar task - include package but exclude sub-packages

Tags: ant

I have a project with `src` package structure like below:

```
project
  -src
    -org.my.service
      A.java
      B.java
    -org.my.service.system
      C.java
      D.java
```

I am trying the below ant

```
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" basedir="../bin">
    <include name="**" />
    <include name="org/my/service/*" />
    <exclude name="org/my/service/**" />
</jar>
```

My built jar is excluding the service package altogether.

I want the jar to include A and B but exclude C and D.
I am looking for a generic solution. The sub-packages will increase with time.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just keep on `exclude` as `system` package is not required and remove other two `include`.

So here goes the `jar` task:

```xml
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" basedir="../bin">
    <exclude name="org/my/service/system/**" />
</jar>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution. But I was looking for something generic because the number of packages at the level of system will increase, say sys1, sys2 and so on. I dont want to change the build script over and over again. Kindly suggest